# How to structure angular.js app components when using ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-router

I decided to use angular-ui-router as opposed to ng-route, due to the stateful routing support.

However, I'm a little puzzled on how to lay out and store my application components in a way that makes sense. Any ideas or examples that may help me out?

Note: I'm using a component-based approach for my structure now. Which means, I've got e.g. "./components/ObjectSidebar". But I'm also very interested in imposing an 'overall application structure' consisting of 'HeaderController', 'MainPageController, FooterController, etc. Would I just include these components all within the same page? How would I structure my application in order to modularize all of the components under 'MainPageController' (which could then include my other components, such as 'ObjectSidebar', so on so forth.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm currently grouping the controllers in a component-based fashion. E.g. ObjectSidebar or ObjectEditView or whatever. But I'm kind of torn, because I also want to have a higher-level controller structure, that would resemble high-level page components, so that I could create a dynamic header, footer, etc. With that said, I'm not particularly sure how to lay out folders/namespaces in a modular, practical fashion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something I wrote a while back that may make a good starting point (or a good conversation starter) around how you could layout a UI Router app with permissions: https://gist.github.com/bvaughn/90343c06467e9bcb8d27

If you'd like to chat further (or have questions about the Gist) feel free to reply. :)

Comment: Thanks. That stuff looks very helpful and is well-detailed. Where would I put the $rootScope code which guards against manual URL entry? Would that just be in my application module? Also, I just replied to the guy above if you want to see more of what I'm confused about

Comment: No probelm. I hope it helps you. :) I'd probably put the `$rootScope` snippet in the main `run` block for your module. You may actually want to check out some of Todd Motto's Angular best-practices guides if you're asking more high-level questions. https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

Comment: Does it make practical sense to have high-level page modularization? E.g. for a chat app: 'home' 'chats' 'settings' where each page loads a general controller that contains the overlaying structure for the pieces inside?

Comment: I think that sort of thing is case-by-case. I can imagine an application where that *would* make sense.